# Mac - Is there an AppKit function for switching applications?

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to change the keyboard shortcuts of my Mac to match the behavior of Windows. I use a custom keyboard and I can change some of the keycodes through firmware, e.g. I can type @ on the same key where I would type it on Windows. Replacing these is no issue in [qmk](https://docs.qmk.fm/#/).

However, what poses a real challenge in qmk is changing key-combinations where MacOS uses a different pattern than Windows. Obviously I replaced `CTRL` with `⌘`, which makes `⌘`+`C`/`V`/`X` and most others work as expected, but there are a few Mac peculiarities. For example `Home` and `End`, which are single keystrokes on Windows, but `⌘`+`<-` and `⌘`+`->` respectively on Mac. For things like these I found very helpful [AppKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit) functions like [moveToBeginningOfLine](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstandardkeybindingresponding/3005245-movetobeginningofline) (thanks to [trusktr](https://gist.github.com/trusktr/1e5e516df4e8032cbc3d) on GitHub). Placing these in `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` works wonders.

However, I could not find a function to switch applications, i.e. to replace `⌘`+`Tab` with `⌥`+`Tab` via the method mentioned above. **Is there an AppKit function for this?**

There is [already a question](https://superuser.com/questions/548146/change-command-tab-to-option-tab-on-mac) on how to swap the behavior, but the answers recommend either using an [invasive tool](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) or [getting used to it](https://superuser.com/a/561295/581735). My question is specifically about an AppKit function. (However if there is a better way to achieve the desired outcome in 2022 on macOS Monterey 12.6, then please tell me.)

I will still be using Windows on a regular basis, so *getting used to it* is simply not an option.

Comment: When I've had jobs where I was switching between Macs and Windows PCs throughout the day, my brain just got used to doing the right thing for the platform I was on at any given moment. So you really can "get used to it" even if you're constantly switching back and forth.

Comment: I 'got used to it' 30 years ago. It's a learned skill, just like any other.